# Multiply elements of a counter object

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

Is there a way I can multiply the elements of a counter object by their count?
For example, if I were to multiply the elements of this:

```
Counter({5: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1})
```

I would get

```
{15, 12, 8}
```

Comment: `c = Counter({5: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1})
print([k*v for k, v in c.items()])` ?

Comment: Bloody legend, that was it, thanks man

Comment: the resulting object that you claim to be after is a `set`. Are you sure you want a set? If you originally started out with `Counter({5: 3, 3: 5})` you would get only `{15}`. Are you fine with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `Counter` object to list of tuples (also `set` is impossible for being ordered so use `list`:

```
>>> c=Counter({5: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1})
>>> [x*y for x,y in c.items()]
[15, 12, 8]
>>>
```

Comment: `{15, 12, 8} == [15, 12, 8] -> False`

Comment: @BlackThunder OP most likely does not know what he is after. Do not be so pedantic. A `set` does not have any order anyhow but one must write it somehow..

Comment: @BlackThunder Edited mine

Comment: I think you should also mention that `set` is not useful here - just try `Counter({5: 3, 3: 5})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension as per @U9-Forward's solution.

An alternative [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) solution is possible with `operator.mul` and `zip`:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import mul

c = Counter({5: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1})

res = list(map(mul, *zip(*c.items())))

# [15, 12, 8]
```

If you really need a `set`, wrap `map` with `set` instead of `list`. The difference is `set` is an unordered collection of unique items, while `list` is an ordered collection with no restriction on duplicates.